# PHP unassociated variables sitting in code doing nothing

Tags: php, variables

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45377001/php-why-is-my-class-refusing-to-be-found) which features the following code piece:

```
<?php
   class Goat{
     public $goat_id;
     public $goat_name;
     public $hashed_password;
  ....
   public static function authenticate($username, $password){

        $is_auth; // This line
        if(!empty($result)){
            $user = array_shift($result);
            $is_auth = Pass_auth::verify_password($password, $user- >hashed_password);
         }

         if($is_auth) {
             return $user;
         }

     ....
    }
 }
```

My question comes from the marked line inside the authenticate function. Not specifically to this example -but in general- what is the point of this `$is_auth;` declaration, just sitting there doing nothing?

I have obviously tried to find an answer before posting here but if this layout/behaviour has a specific name I don't know it.

I have made some sandbox variations and am surprised to find that none of them produce any errors, the below code is error free:

```
<?php
   error_reporting(E_ALL);

   $small = "tree";
   //$small = false; //swapping var value types makes no difference.
   $small;

   $sdgdfghdgd;
```

## So my questions are:

- What is the name for this unassociated variable usage?
- Is there any point to this?

  - If so; what?
- Why doesn't this produce any error or warning (I'm **not** saying it should, necessarily, just curious)?

Comment: One to which hasn't responded to [my last comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45377001/php-why-is-my-class-refusing-to-be-found#comment77716822_45377001) I might add. (20 mins. prior to this comment).

Comment: @Fred-ii- I got completely distracted by this curiosity, I asked the OP about why that line (above) is there and they didn't respond to that enquiry, either. I can't see any point to it but find it curious how it also doesn't seem to generate any errors, so wondering if there's a usage I was now aware of. . . .. .

Comment: It's anybody's guess and as to the OS they used which stands to be important; I never got anything back from it. So, I'm just as in the dark as you.

Comment: Nice title. **variables sitting in code doing nothing** - I like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$is_auth;
```

is a perfectly valid [PHP expression](http://php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php). It's value is the value of `$is_auth` and it doesn't have any effect.

The PHP compiler is smart enough to detect that the expression is useless (because it's value is not used and it doesn't have any side effect) and it doesn't generate any opcode for it.

If it were generating any code, that code should trigger an `E_NOTICE` because the variable is not defined yet.

The situation changes when the expression involves an array. Even if, conceptually, the expression `$a['foo'];` is equivalent with `$is_auth;`, `$a['foo'];` is not optimized out by the compiler. It is evaluated and it triggers the expected `E_NOTICE` when `$a` is not defined or it doesn't have the key `'foo'`.

Comment: I realise the $var can be a valid expression (*I guess it equates to `null` as nothing happens to the variable value?*), but yes, I was expecting at least an `E_NOTICE`  that it's there, regardless of if its defined no action is being performed. I guess you know not of any practical usage or reasoning for this (i'd imagine there isn't one ... but)

Comment: It is not the same as `NULL` and there is no reason to trigger an `E_NOTICE` if the variable is defined. Think how `$x = $y;` is executed. The value of `$y` is evaluated (it triggers an `E_NOTICE` only if `$y` is not defined) then the value is stored in `$x`. Here the `$x = ` part is missing, so the evaluation of the expression should stop after `$y` is evaluated. But it seems PHP is smart enough (at least in this case) to avoid doing an useless evaluation.